# Count 2 elements Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I count 2 columns in spark?

I test it. But it's not the good way ..

```
joinDF = logDF.join(logDF2,"day_number")
compareNumberRequestTraffic = joinDF.groupBy("day_number") \
    .agg(functions.count("request","request2")) \
    .show()
```

I have the error :

```
() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I want ton have on output

```
day_number      count(request)     count(request2)
2015-01-03                5                   7
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry, I edit the question @GrantWinney

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not write count with 2 arguments, but 2 counts in agg function

```
joinDF = logDF.join(logDF2,"day_number")
compareNumberRequestTraffic = joinDF.groupBy("day_number") \
    .agg(functions.count("request"), functions.count("request2")) \
    .show()
```